# chapter number in citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am using `chapterbib` and everything seems to be working, but I would like my citations to appear as `[x.1]`, `[x.2]`, etc. where `x` is the chapter number. I cannot find how to do this, but I have a book set it Latex where (I think) it was done. Is is possible?

example: instead of

```
[1] Jones, "Anteaters, journal of diet, 1999.
```

I would like

```
[9.1] Jones, "Anteaters, journal of diet, 1999.
```

I am using documentclass book and bibliographystyle{plain}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want with the `chapterbib` package, you have to add the following command to your preamble

```
\CitationPrefix{\thechapter.}
```

All your citations and bibliography items in the bibliographies will be numbered as you want.

Obviously it won't affect an overall bibliography, but only chapter-bibliographies.

Comment: Thanks, but something doesn't work I get:Undefined control sequence 1.6 \CitationPrefix{\thechapter}

Comment: What is your document class?

Comment: I am using \usepackage{chapterbib} with no arguments. Do you think I need a [\sectionbib] or other argument?

Comment: document class is book

Comment: @Wesley It shouldn't depend on this, anyway try to use `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}`

Comment: right. It didn't. I get the same \CitationPrefix[sectionbib]{chapterbib} error message

Comment: @Wesley the error you mentioned usually occurs when using classes where `\chapter` (and consequently `\thechapter`) are not defined, like `article`. It should not happen with `book` class. Please add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/27635) to your original question where you also specify the bibliography style you are using.

Comment: Done. The style is plain.

Comment: I am very grateful for any and all help. I am running chapterbib in book class with \bibliographystyle{plain} on a mac running 10.8.4

Answer (score 1):

After much work, I figured out that my platform had the 2004 version of chapterbib.sty, and the CitationPrefix function is not defined. I downloaded the 2010 version of chapterbib.sty and it runs fine. Problem closed.